# How to move between pinned/favorited apps in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, dock, favorites

In Ubuntu 17 if you press <kbd>super</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> you can move between pinned applications on dock and then run them if you want. How I can do this in Ubuntu 18.04?

I know that if I press <kbd>super</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> I can see numbers and then choose one but I want to have that ability to move between apps.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Shell extensions can alter the behaviour of the shell. The extension [Super+Tab Launcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1133/supertab-launcher/) includes all favorites in your Alt+Tab dialog to do what you want. If already running, you can switch to it, if not yet running, it will launch.

Just for your additional information, there is a way in the Ubuntu desktop to switch to the dash using the keyboard. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> to go to the overview. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and select Dash from the pop-up. Now, you can navigate in the Dash with the arrow keys. Allegedly, this is a slow method that is hardly discoverable. You may want to turn to the extension instead.

*Note* in case you did not know, you can also immediately launch a favorite by directly pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the link but when I went to that link I faced: `We cannot detect a running copy of GNOME on this system, so some parts of the interface may be disabled. See our troubleshooting entry for more information.` so I installed it by cloning the repo but nothing happens when I press super+tab. How can I activate it? There is no instruction in the repo's README.

Comment: Yes, but how to enable installing Gnome extensions is another question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions